# Do we have to use "this" keyword in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing a small example to validate `Name`, `Email`, `Password` and `ConfirmPassword` via typescript.

I've tried:

```
interface IValidation {
    CheckingNameAndEmail(): boolean;
    CheckingPasswordAndConfirmPassword(): boolean;
}

class Validation implements IValidation {
    private Input: string;
    private Type: string;

    constructor(input: string, _type: string) {
        this.Input = input;
        this.Type = _type;
    }

    Validate = function () {
        switch (this.Type) {
            case 'Name':
            case 'Email':
                return this.CheckingNameAndEmail()
            case 'Password':
            case 'ConfirmPassword':
                return this.CheckingPasswordAndConfirmPassword()
        }
    };

    CheckingNameAndEmail = function () {
        var reg = this.Type == 'Name'
            ? new RegExp('^.{4,16}$')
            : new RegExp('^((([0-9]?)[a-zA-Z0-9]([0-9]?))+[\._-]??[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+@{1}?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\._-]??[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.(com|net|org|vn){1}$')
        return reg.test(this.Input)
    };

    CheckingPasswordAndConfirmPassword = function () {
        var reg = new RegExp('^.{6,50}$');
        return reg.test(this.Input)
    };
}
```

As you can see, I `must` use `this` keyword in the example. If not, it will throw me error (Like: `Cannot find ...`).

So my question is: How to avoid calling `this` multiple times in typescript?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `this`? Typing?

Comment: @hansmaad Yes. Shorthand for typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to explicitly write `this` in Typesript. Sometimes it might be usefull to use an additional local variable to save typing and to write minification friendly code. Consider this example:

```
foo() {
    if (this.someAwesomeMember.bar) {
        var f = this.someAwesomeMember.bar(123);
        var b = this.someAwesomeMember.bar(321);
        // do more stuff with this awesome member
    }
}
```

Since we're referencing the awesome member using `this` all the time, there is not much to minify here. We can do better:

```
foo() {
    var someAwesomeMember = this.someAwesomeMember;
    if (someAwesomeMember.bar) {
        var f = someAwesomeMember.bar(123);
        var b = someAwesomeMember.bar(321);
        // do more stuff with this awesome member
    }
}
```

Which can be minified to something like

```
var a=this.someAwesomeMember;if(a.bar){var f=a.bar(123);var b=a.bar(321);}
```

Note, that it might decrease readability to replace `this` by another local variable. So you have to judge carefully here.

Comment: Vote up for `replace this by another local variable` :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't avoid it. It's a property of the language.

`<hard-learned-lesson>`I tend to avoid these kind of shortcuts when I write my code because it makes it harder for others to read it. Readability is a key thing when you target to write good code (for yourself and for others).`</hard-learned-lesson>`