# Typescript: How to call a variable not using "this" everywhere

Tags: typescript, angular

As the example below, how to avoid write "**this**" everywhere, is there a way to write `heroes, myHero,lastone` without "**`this`**" ? Just like common javascript

[image]

Comment: try `this=xyz` then use `xyz` instead of `this`

Comment: It *is* possible (with certain shenanigans) but it doesn't make sense. So stick to traditional notation.

Comment: @PardeepJain replace `this` to `xyz` is meaningless, I just want to write variable directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894886/do-we-have-to-use-this-keyword-in-typescript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a class you are dealing with **properties** and **methods**, not *variables* and *functions*. That's why `this` is required - it refers to the instance of a class.

You can still use local variables and functions inside class methods, but if you need to access class (instance) property or call it's methods you have to use `this`.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare your variable out of your class:

```
var heroes = {...}
class AppC {
    test() {
        //heroes 
    }
}
```

I DO NOT advise to do that.